# Declaration of multiple properties in one line

Tags: php, oop, properties

Can I declare more than one php properties in one line, especially if I have no need to initialize them right there, like we can declare in jquery.

JQuery Example

```
var a, b, c;
```

May I expect inside php class like below?

```
var $a, $b, $c;
```

I have searched for my question but unfortunately didn't find anything helpful.

Comment: That is Javascript. jQuery is a library, not a language. Also, have you tried to do it in PHP? If you have then what happened? If you have not tried it then why not?!

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen that is php ;) some people likes var to declared public objects

Comment: @jycr753 The second code example, yes. And?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen yeah I see your point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can

```
class myclass {
public $a, $b = 3, $c;
}

$i = new myclass();

$i->a = 2;
echo $i->a; // 2
echo $i->b; // 3
```

Answer (score 2):

The use of `var` will raise no E_STRICT in PHP 5.3, this said if you want to create this kind declaration you could use `list`

```
$info = array('coffee', 'brown', 'caffeine');
list($drink, $color, $power) = $info;
//you can use it like this
echo "I like to drink {$brown} {$coffee} with 100% {$caffeine}";
```

Also you can do the following inside a class for example:

```
class Something {
   //this way
   private $one, $two;
   //also can be done with globals
   global $post, $product, $woocommerce;

}
```